# Prove Or Disprove: tr(AB)=tr(A)*tr(B)

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

$\mathrm{tr}(AB)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \sum\limits_{j=1}^n a_{ij}*b_{ji}$

$\mathrm{tr}(A)*\mathrm{tr}(B)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_{ii}*\sum\limits_{i=1}^n b_{ii}$

Therefore $\mathrm{tr}(AB) \neq \mathrm{tr}(A)*\mathrm{tr}(B)$

Is the proof valid?

Comment: $\sum a_i\sum b_i\neq \sum a_ib_i$!!!

Comment: Is there a question? (If you want your proof validated, say so and include the proof-verifcation tag).

Comment: Done the edit, and now?

Comment: @Semiclassical thanks

Comment: (What is true, however, is that ${\rm tr}(AB)={\rm tr}(BA)$

Comment: It is true for $n = 1$...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It is false. Let's think small. Consider the identity matrix, of order $n > 1$. Then: $$n = \mathrm{tr}(I) = \mathrm{tr}(I \cdot I) \neq \mathrm{tr}(I)~ \mathrm{tr}(I) = n^2$$
It is important to try some silly cases and gain intuition about the affirmation before tackling summations, etc.

Answer (score 5):

You have not given a reason why those expressions are not identically equal.  They will be equal in some special cases.  The easiest way to prove that such an identity doesn't hold is to give a counterexample.  Try 2-by-2 matrices.